# Why do I keep getting axios error 404 on my Mac when I run it on my Mac

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am a new developer and I keep getting this error when I run my React app on my Mac:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

The error is primarily for my localhost/showpasswords and /addpassword.  The data is supposed to be sent to mysql but nothing gets sent and my result grid/table shows null values. I’m  not sure whether this error is because I’m connecting to the wrong port or whether there is a Mac dependency/library I needed to download. Any insight and help will be appreciated

Here’s my client side with Axios:

```
import "./App.css";
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [passwordList, setPasswordList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/showpasswords").then((response) => {
      setPasswordList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
  
  const addPassword = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/addpassword",  {
      password: password, 
      title: title,
    });
  };

  const decryptPassword = (encryption) => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/decryptpassword", {
      password: encryption.password, 
      iv: encryption.iv,
    }).then((response) => {
      setPasswordList(
        passwordList.map((val) => {
          return val.id == encryption.id 
            ? {
              id: val.id, 
              password: val.password, 
              title: response.data, 
              iv: val.iv,
              } 
            : val;
        })
      );
    });
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div  className="AddsPassword">
        <input 
          type="text" 
          placeholder="Ex. password123" 
          onChange={(event) => {
            setPassword(event.target.value);
        }}
      />    
      <input 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="Ex. Facebook" 
        onChange={(event) => {
          setTitle(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={addPassword}> Add Password</button>
    </div>
```

Here’s my server:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = 3001;

const {encrypt, decrypt} = require("./EncryptionHandler");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user: "root",
    host: "localhost",
    password: "password",
    database: "PasswordManager",
});

app.post("/addpassword", (req, res) => {
    const { password, title} = req.body;
    const hashedPassword = encrypt(password);
    db.query(
        "INSERT INTO passwords (password, title, iv) VALUES (?,?,?)",
        [hashedPassword.password, title, hashedPassword.iv],
        (err, result) =>  {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.send("Success");
            }
        }
    );
});

app.get("/showpasswords", (req, res) => {
    db.query("SELECT * FROM passwords;", (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
});

app.post("/decryptpassword", (req, res) => {
    res.send(decrypt(req.body));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server is running");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a db connection issue.

```js
app.get("/showpasswords", (req, res) => {
    db.connect((err){
     if(err) throw err;
     console.log("DB connected");
     // your code.
     db.query("SELECT * FROM passwords;", (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

See if you can connect to the DB if not then it will throw you an error. Let me know if this works.